# How to set focus of raspberry pi camera module V2?

Tags: raspberry-pi, setfocus

When I searched about it on google and youtube I get this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6VhRVH3Z6Y

In the video the focus of the camera is set physically by rotating lens of the camera but the lens of the camera is very sensitive, is there any other way to set the focus of camera module either by code or physically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Physics doesn’t allow for that. No servo motor, no software. And the lens/sensor distance is the only thing that matters here. It works for plenty of people me included. What exactly is giving you problems?

Comment: I want to scan barcode using raspberry pi camera module v2 but the problem is that whenever I click a photo from the camera, the barcode in the image is getting blur so its difficult to scan barcode using picam.

Comment: I understand that. But the pi camera has no auto focus such as more sophisticated cameras. So you have to mechanically adjust it. Or use a different camera.

Comment: @YashAgrawal I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?